# Custom plugin for e-mail automatic replies

Tags: python, email, plugins, outlook

do you know a way to create some king of plugin for automatic replies personalization?
If an e-mail is something like:

> "Dear Sender, I am on vacation. I will be back on 27th of September"

I want from plugin to change "Sender" to name of an original mail sender.
This plugin should work for Outlook and Gmail.
A reply sent to Josh should look something like this:

> Dear Josh, I am on vacation. I will be back on 27th of September.